# Communication Serially via USB cable with Samsung S4

Tags: android, arduino, serial-communication

I want to communicate with my samsung s4 serially. and I need to use the wire. This is for a testing purpose and my final aim is to communicate directly with my arduino. Before that I wanted do this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library  **USB Serial** for communication directly from your android phone to the **audino** using the OTG Cable.Below is the link for usbserial and sample code.

https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Comment: It seems this is correct. I will work on this and give you the feed back. Thank you :D